# Adding a new hard drive to RAID1 software RAID fails

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, diskutil, raid

I've got a Mac Pro 1.1 running macOS Server 10.6.8 that I want to use as a RAID-Server. I use Disk Utility to run a RAID1 set with two 500GB hard drives.

Now adding a third 500GB hard drive to the existing RAID-Set with `diskutil appleraid add member` fails by showing me the following error message:

Error: -9911: The target disk appears to be too small to add to this RAID set

But when I delete the RAID-Set and set it up with all three hard drives together, the RAID is being created without any problem.

I belive that it could have something to do with the fact, that the third hard drive is a different model (different company), and the other two are the exact same. But if that would be the case, then I could not replace a hard drive in a RAID-Set, even if it would be from the same company and the same model line – since even those can change over time – except if I buy the exact same one – right?

---

I want to be sure that Apple RAID is capable of adding a new drive to an existing RAID if I have to swap a damaged one. Is anyone able to help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: RAID-1 is **TWO** disks. It is called a "mirror" meaning disk one is a mirror (duplicate) of disk 2 you cant use 3 disks in RAID-1. You can do a RAID-5 array though with 3 disks.

Comment: As far as I know, you can mirror onto as many drives as you want, given the controller supports it (hardware RAID). But I am using a software RAID, which should give me a RAID1 with as many hard drives as I want.
Check this out: https://superuser.com/questions/489793/can-raid-1-have-more-than-two-drives

Comment: Don't cross post to multiple stack exchange sites. Pick one & stick to it - https://superuser.com/questions/1476652/adding-a-new-hard-drive-to-raid1-software-raid-fails

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry for that – didn't know about that rule.

Answer (score 1):

I did not know, that it's not ok to cross post over multiple platforms – sorry for that.

However on superuser I got an answer to my problem, so here is the link once again:
**https://superuser.com/questions/1476652/adding-a-new-hard-drive-to-raid1-software-raid-fails**